# How can I populate two beans from my form with Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, webforms, javabeans

So I am using Spring MVC 3 with annotations.

I have a simple html form (ExtJS actually) that has three fields.

```
1) Username
2) Password
3) Color
```

OK, so `username` and `password` belong to a databean called `User`.  `color` belongs to another bean called `Color`.

In my UserController, I have:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
  public String handleLogin(  @ModelAttribute("user") User paUser, 
                              @ModelAttribute("color") Color paColor, 
                              ModelMap map) {

    // at this point "paUser" contains both username AND password submitted from form

    // however, there is nothing in "paColor"

    ...

    return "user.jsp"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm new to Spring, btw.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you would create a new class that represents the form (this is known as a form-backing object), such as `UserColorForm`, that contains properties for each of the inputs in the request body.

Your controller method would then look like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String handleLogin(UserColorForm form, ModelMap map) {
    // now you can work with form.getUsername(), form.getColor() etc.
```

If the FBO bean has property names that match the form input names, Spring will bind the input in the request directly to the properties. i.e. if the form input is `username=matt&color=blue` then Spring will create a new instance of my form and call `setUsername("matt")` and `setColor("blue")`.

By the way, you probably don't want the method to be annotated with `@ResponseBody` if you are going to return the name of the view from the method (`user.jsp`). `@ResponseBody` means that the return value of the method should be written directly to the response stream.

Comment: So, do you have an example of the FBO?  Oh, yeah, the @ResponseBody is there because I actually return JSON data.  I was just trying to keep the pseudo code simple.  :-)

Comment: Usually the FBO is a simple class that just has getters and setters for each of the properties in the form - `getUsername()`/`setUsername()`, `getColor()`/`setColor()` etc.